# Плавный перебор элементов

Tags: jquery, javascript

Задача:
1) При загрузки страницы, элементы поочередно перебирались
2) При наведении курсора на один из элементов, перебор останавливался и выделялся элемент над которым курсор
3) При увидении курсора со всех элементов, перебор элементов возобновлялся как в п.1

Первый и второй пункт я реализовал, третий тоже практически, но вот перебор становиться странным, не равномерным, начинаются не равномерные задержки, выделение прыгает туда, сюда. Подскажите, как стабилизировать поэлементный обход элементов?

PS Браузер начинает тормозить при долгой работе данного скрипта.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
.b-hot-item-selected{
    border:1px solid red;
}
</style>

<ul class="b-hot-items h-hot-items__new">
    <li class="b-hot-item tab-t-m">Text_1</li>
    <li class="b-hot-item tab-t-m">Text_22</li>
    <li class="b-hot-item tab-t-m">Text_333</li>
    <li class="b-hot-item tab-t-m">Text_4444</li>
    <li class="b-hot-item tab-t-m">Text_55555</li>
</ul>

<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    function animateIt(){
        a = $(".h-hot-items__new > .tab-t-m").hasClass("b-hot-item-selected");
        if (a == false){
            $(".h-hot-items__new .tab-t-m:first-child").toggleClass("b-hot-item-selected");
        }
        var t = setTimeout(function() {
            $(".b-hot-item-selected").next().toggleClass("b-hot-item-selected").prev().toggleClass("b-hot-item-selected");
        }, 1000);

        b = $(".h-hot-items__new .tab-t-m:last-child").hasClass("b-hot-item-selected");
        if (b == true){
            var t = setTimeout(function() {
                $(".h-hot-items__new > .tab-t-m").removeClass("b-hot-item-selected");
                $(".h-hot-items__new .tab-t-m:first-child").toggleClass("b-hot-item-selected");
            }, 1000);
        }
        var t = setTimeout(animateIt, 1000);
        $(".tab-t-m").hover(
            function () {
                clearTimeout(t);
                $(".h-hot-items__new > .tab-t-m").removeClass("b-hot-item-selected");
                $(this).toggleClass("b-hot-item-selected");
            },
            function () {
                    $(this).toggleClass("b-hot-item-selected");
            }
        );
        $(".h-hot-items__new").hover(function () {},
            function () {
                animateIt();
            }
        );
    }
    animateIt();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Тормозить начинает, как я понимаю, потому что Вы на каждый тик `animateIt` добавляете все новых и новых обработчиков. Хотя я не вдавался в логику его работы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что-то такое? http://jsfiddle.net/drdaeman/b2Upf/

```
<ul id="items">
    <li class="item selected">Item 1</li>
    <li class="item">Item 2</li>
    <li class="item">Item 3</li>
    <li class="item">Item 4</li>
    <li class="item">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

и

```
#items .item {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
#items .selected {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

и

```
var animation_locked = false;

function animation_tick() {
    if (animation_locked) return;

    var current = $("#items .item.selected");
    var next = current.next(".item");
    if (!next.length) { next = $("#items .item:first"); }

    next.addClass("selected");
    current.removeClass("selected");
}

$("#items .item").mouseenter(function(e) {
    animation_locked = true;
    $("#items .item.selected").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});

$("#items .item").mouseleave(function(e) {
    animation_locked = false;
});

setInterval(animation_tick, 1000);
```

Comment: Да, то что нужно, печально только что не по моему коду (хотелось понять в чём у меня ошибка), а написали полностью свой, но спорить сложно, сделано и работает на отлично. Спасибо.

Comment: У Вас слишком много в коде всего, мне было откровенно лень разбираться, извините. Много прыжков next()/prev(), куча лишней логики, массово плодящиеся таймауты (в итоге их становится слишком много и браузер «тормозит»). Конструкция «`function () { animateIt(); }`», например, вообще лишена смысла — достаточно просто «`animateIt`» (без «`()`»).

Comment: Ну я так и понял что проще было написать своё чем ковыряться в чужом стремном.